# Resources not being loaded in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, view

I added a new cshtml razor file into my asp.net MVC 4 project. I just added

```
@model Clockit.Models.UserDetails
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

to the start of an existing HTML page which I had, to convert the html file to a cshtml. When I load the page, it just gives me blank text without any CSS.

My Chrome console says

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:20591/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

My corresponding cshtml code to that error is

```
<link href="../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Why isn't the razor able to find the resourses?

Comment: Could you ensure that **font-awesome.min.css** exists under `/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/`?

Comment: None of the css files seem to be loading, though they exist.